# Video overlay do not display video in folium python

Tags: python, folium

```
import folium

print(folium.__version__)

m = folium.Map(location=[22.5, -115], zoom_start=4)

video = folium.raster_layers.VideoOverlay(
    video_url='https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00188/patricia_nasa.webm',
    bounds=[[32, -130], [13, -100]]
)

video.add_to(m)

m.save( 'VideoOverlayLayer.html')
```

I am trying to overlay a video in the top of a map. What I got right now is a static image not a video. Though I am using videoOverlay method in folium. 
Here is folium official document. Do I have to use URL? Is that possible pass video located in the same folder of this python file? Thanks for any helps!
https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html

Comment: Running your code I get a video over the map.  What version of folium do you use?

Comment: My folium version is 0.11.0. I think it is most recent version  folium

Comment: I have the same version and your code works well. What browser do you use?

Comment: Let me try to use different browser! Thanks for helping!